# How to test a nested component in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I'm learning Jest with React and I would like to understand how to test if a component is rendered.

In my App.js I did this:

```
import React from "react";
import AppLayout from "./Components/AppLayout";

function App() {
    return <AppLayout />;
}

export default App;
```

My test

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import App from "./App";
import AppLayout from "./Components/AppLayout";

describe("App", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => (wrapper = shallow(<App />)));

    it("should render the App", () => {
        console.log(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<AppLayout />));
        expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<AppLayout />)).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

This above test fails with False:

```
Expected: true
Received: false
```

I don't understand how to make this to pass and what should be this test actually as what I need is just to have a check when the App renders the AppLayout the main app container.

Comment: use console.log(wrapper.debug()) to help you see what is going on...

Comment: Shallow mounting doesn't render children. This also isn't a very useful test as you are really just testing that react (don't test 3rd party code). If you want to test "nested" components then just write a test that renders that component in isolation.

Comment: The test case passes. Can't reproduce it.